# Uniqueness of a solution of a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f,g \in L^{\infty}([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d$ and $F:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ function. Let us consider the two differential equations:
$$
\dot{x}(t)=F(x(t),f(t)), \quad \dot{x}(t)=F(x(t),g(t)), \quad x(0)= a \in \mathbb{R}^n
,$$
for almost every $t\in [0,1]$. Can I deduce necessarly that $f=g$ for almost every $t\in [0,1]$ (from the uniqueness of Cauchy Lipschitz's result)?

Is there some hypothesis that needs to take place for $f=g$ a.e.

Comment: What happens if $F$ depends on the first variable?

Comment: @geetha290krm I guess we can (at first) consider the question without dependence of the first variable.

Comment: How about $F(x,y)=y^{2}, f=-g$